# Last tick label not showing?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code gives me a graph of apple's stock price, but it's missing the last label.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

data = pd.read_csv('data_assign_p3-1.csv')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
axes.plot(data['DATE'], data['APPLE'])
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))
fig.suptitle('Apple')
plt.show()
```

[image: Stock price of Apple]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem. Please check the start and end dates for which you are picking up the data. It looks like you are using `13-02-2007` as the start date of around `20-01-2013`. Downloading the same data from Yahoo Finance has no entry from 18th-22nd. As you have not converted the data into datetime, python thinks these are categorical values and misses that date. Convert the column to Datetime and, if required, format the output x-axis dates as below. I was able to get it to work with these changes. Hope this helps.

```
from random import random
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

data = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'], format='%d-%m-%Y') ##Convert
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
axes.plot(data['DATE'], data['APPLE'])
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')) 
fig.suptitle('Apple')
plt.show()
```

[image]